# How to set Record in Typescript for string and boolean value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, record

all.

I have a Formik field in React and need to set the values of the fields to a string or a boolean

```
const handleSubmit = async (values: Record<string, string>) => {
    const checkoutDetails = await getCheckout({ checkoutId: checkoutId });
    if (checkoutDetails.errors) {
        setSubmitError(true);
        return;
    }

    const email = checkoutDetails.data.checkoutById.customer?.email;
    const customer = await addCustomer({
        firstName: values.firstName,
        lastName: values.lastName,
        checkoutId: checkoutId as string,
        customerId: null,
        email: email,
        ochId: null,
        emailMarketingConsent: values.emailMarketing as unknown as boolean,
        smsMarketingConsent: values.smsMarketing as unknown as boolean,
    });
```

With the above code I have to cast the last two values as they are boolean values, I have tried a few ways including writing custom types but it seems to error one way or the other

Do not get me wrong, it does work like this, but I feel there is a better way without typecasting to unknown as boolean.

Can anyone show me how to set the Record type so I do not need to cast it?

Thank you!

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the code in the question to be a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  Right now you have various undeclared values like `getCheckout` and `checkoutId`.  If you make a self-contained example, then I could immediately get to work on the problem instead of trying to re-create it (or just suggesting an approach that I can't test, which could be worse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Record<string, string| boolean>` could be a way but you'll still need the type assertion.

or you could do an intersection :

```
type Foo  = Record<string, string> & {emailMarketing: boolean, smsMarketing: boolean}

declare const foo:Foo;
 
foo.firstName // string
foo.emailMarketing // boolean;
foo.smsMarketing // boolean;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKUC8UBKEDGcBOATAHgGdgcBLAOwHMAaKE86gPigDIoBvCAWwEMyANgFleOANYRglKgC4oAIwQCIvCnSLciI8ZOlzFcZaoC%20AKFN4sA0dGwUSUAGYIZ8OAG5TUU87gA6RzIcEgA5Xm5oAHpI%20lJpHwQ-Hn5hUQkpaihohSUVCk9fPw0tNN1M7IMjfKA)

Comment: Could be wrong but I think with the updated `Record<string, string| boolean>` he'll not need any casting since its likely inferred from the underlying `addCustomer` input type.

Comment: [Example playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKUC8UBKEDGcBOATAHgGdgcBLAOwHMAaKAIwQBsIBDCgPigCg8snWOaNgokoAMwQAueHADc3biLEQAHqwC2YFjAooAFHDDAiUqAG9xZHCQBymiGZLlqdCBtZkmAWUEBrCGBKKjNGOBZ2OiINIl8cAKDqUOY2CgBfAEoULjCIim4ebjVNbQhdfXMCpAlrOwczACJgCBIGmiqkd08ff0Dgs1IAVwh26qho2N7EkIlWJiIIbkygA)

Comment: I'll add though this solution as stronger guarantees and probably certain TS config settings mean its needed. Im upvoting this :)

Comment: @adsy Your exemple doesn't make any sense. [Playgroudn](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAlCBjOAnAJgHgGdhsBLAOwHMAaKAIwQBsIBDcqAHymLKoD4AULkyMW2aFnLEoAMwQAuWAgDcAgZOkQAHiwC2YZjHYoAFHDDBCigN6zS2YgDk9ERTwo0oEXS1KMAsmIA1hDAHooMcMxstIS6hIHYIWFUEUys7AC+AJTIfFAAbnCkuGpycAB0MvZOLlAA9PXcJB4C5RXevgHBoR4NTZHR5KrtcQk9KZT99OlsqgLaegYQRibWAlCbdg7AzrqusghVNbt1LITNvDQbW51+icnhh5V33Um9VFDnM1EZ1DebMYPD6URSjeLAyZfC6DDICHJAA)

Comment: How so? Im creating a dummy function thats typed to mimick the probably typed `addCustomer` he has. The point is, TS will accept it without cast as it will attempt to infer from the fn param type.

Comment: Oh god sorry! You are totally right. My fault for rushing -- I left in some cast from playing with it. Sorry for confusion

Comment: Record<string, string| boolean> does not work as then it expects the props in the next component to be string or booleans, each value that is. They will not be strings or booleans, they will all be strings with the last two values being booleans.